# How to make custom data class subscriptable

Tags: python-3.x, pydantic

Consider this data class derived from the [`pydantic`](https://pypi.org/project/pydantic/) package:

```
from typing import List
from pydantic import BaseModel 
class Bucket(BaseModel):
    setting: List[str]
    fight_1: List[int]
    cause_1: List[str]
```

let `my_bucket` be an instance of `Bucket`:

```
my_bucket = Bucket(setting=['some_value'], fight_1=[0], cause_1=['other_value'])
```

basically I would like to be able to do

```
my_bucket['setting']
```

and get back `['some_value']`, but instead I get:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-cacbdc1698e9> in <module>
----> 1 my_bucket['setting']

TypeError: 'Bucket' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: You need to define `__getitem__`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

#### With pydantic

You can access your property as an attribute in pydantic.

```py
my_bucket = Bucket(setting=['some_value'], fight_1=[0], cause_1=['other_value'])
print(my_bucket.setting)  # ['some_value']
```

If you want to use `[]` to access it, you need to define `__getitem__`:

```py
from typing import List
from pydantic import BaseModel


class Bucket(BaseModel):
    setting: List[str]
    fight_1: List[int]
    cause_1: List[str]

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return getattr(self, item)


my_bucket = Bucket(setting=['some_value'], fight_1=[0], cause_1=['other_value'])
print(my_bucket['setting'])  # ['some_value']
```

#### Without pydantic

If you don't want to use `pydantic` and create your custom dataclass you can do this:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass
class CustomDataClass:
    data: int

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return getattr(self, item)


obj = CustomDataClass(42)
print(obj.data)  # 42
print(obj["data"])  # 42, needs __getitem__ to be implemented
```

Answer (score 4):

For a python dataclass this works for me:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class MyCustomRequest:
    request: Dict
        
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return super().__getattribute__(key)
```

```py
>>> a = MyCustomRequest({"a":10})
>>> a["request"]
{"a":10}
>>> a.request
{"a": 10}
```

Comment: Any advantages (or drawbacks) on using `dataclass.__getattribute__()` instead of plain `getattr()`?